# Android toast notification is not working

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android and I am trying to create a toast notification using this code

Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).Show(true);
Pls what did I get wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code 
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

Please note the caps in show method. And it  doesn't require a true parameter.

Comment: non-sense, why is this question asked please remove it...and u Mr@Micheal Peter u shouldn't answer...

Comment: The fellow who is asking has not done any kind of research and simply coming and asking a question here..This is not a site to play and give reputations for ur friends...

Answer (score 0):

What context do you use? 
Also do you get any error?

Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

Is the general syntax, how do you use it?